# Somar valores numéricos em arquivos de texto com Python

Tags: python-3.x, arquivo

estou escrevendo um pequeno projeto em Python que consiste em um aplicativo que vai adicionando gastos, armazenando o nome e o valor dos gastos em um arquivo de texto e printando na linha de comando, e no final computando a soma do valor dos gastos. A ideia é que a cada vez que abro o aplicativo, eu possa somar novos valores ao valor total de gastos anterior. Por exemplo, o total de gastos deu 100, o programa armazena esse valor e quando eu abrir de novo, posso adicionar um gasto de 20 reais efazer o programa mostrar 120. É possível realizar esse tipo de operação trabalhando somente com python e arquivos?

Segue o código do projeto

````
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            opc = int(input(f'''=================================================
              MENU PRINCIPAL
=================================================
[1] Visualizar lista de compras
[2] Atualizar gastos
[3] Sair 
=================================================

Sua opção: '''))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print('Tipo de dado digitado inválido! Digite novamente')
        else:
            break           
    if opc == 1:
        with open("arquivo.txt") as n:
            nome = n.read()
            print('='*49)
            print(nome)
            print('='*49)            
    elif opc == 2:        
        with open("arquivo.txt",'a') as n: 
            while True:                   
                x = str(input(f'Tipo de gasto: '))
                t = x.strip().capitalize()
                if len(t) < 20:
                    b = 20 - len(t)
                    h = t + (' '*b)
                if x.isalpha() == False:
                    print(f'Digite novamente: ')
                else:
                    break                  
            while True:
                try:                    
                    y = float(input(f'Valor do gasto (R$): '))
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    print('Tipo de dado digitado inválido! Digite novamente')

                else:
                    valores.append(y)
                    break 

            z = str(y)                    
            n.write(h)
            n.write(f'\t\t R${z}')
            n.write('\n')
            print(f'''
Novo registro de {x} adicionado''')

            soma = 0
            for i in valores:
                soma += i
            print(f'''
Soma                R${soma}''')

    elif opc == 3:
        print(f'Obrigado, volte sempre! ')
        break
    else:
        print(f'Opção inválida! Tente novamente: ')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode utilizar o `open` para abrir um arquivo em formato de leitura, obter o valor, somá-lo dentro do programa e depois escrever o arquivo novamente com o valor atualizado. Exemplo:

```
def atualizaGastos(valor):
    with open("data.txt") as file:
        gastos = float(file.read())
    with open("data.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(str(gastos+valor))
```

Caso o arquivo possua mais informação do que um simples número (gastos), você deverá saber a posição exata deste número no arquivo ou então, utilizar o módulo `re` para obter os gastos em qualquer parte do arquivo. Se você não sabe o que são **Expressões Regulares** pesquise primeiro por esse assunto e depois utilize o módulo `re` para obter os valores desejados no arquivo.